# How can I iterate over the polymorphic union of two vectors?

Tags: c++, physics, stdvector, dynamic-cast

I need an inexpensive way to iterate over the combination of two vectors...

I have two classes I"m trying to work with in a physics simulation,`A` and `B` which inherits from `A`.

The idea is:

```cpp
std::vector<A*> items; // contains As and Bs
for (A* item : items) {
    item->doWorkA();
    if((B* itemB = dynamic_cast<B*>(a)) != nullptr)
        itemB->doWorkB();
    
    for(A* item2 : items) {
        if(item == item2)
            continue;

        item.doSomethingTo(item2);
    }
}
```

This is run an arbitrary number of times per second, so I believe the dynamic casts at runtime will be very expensive.

What I've resolved to do is create two separate vectors for each type, so that the dynamic cast is only done once (rather than at each arbitrary time step), and instead handle all the `B` specific work on the B vector. Then I'd do all of the `A` work on the union of the two vectors.

Something like this:

```cpp
std::vector<A*> aItems;
std::vector<B*> bItems;
for (B* itemB : bItems) {
    itemB->doWorkB();
}

for (A* item : aItems UNION bItems) {
    item.doWorkA();
    for(A* item2 : aItems UNION bItems) {
        if(item == item2)
            continue;

        item.doSomethingTo(item2);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this "union" in an **efficient** manner?

Comment: "I believe the dynamic casts at runtime will be very expensive" Is this belief founded on actual measurements? `dynamic_cast` is expensive compared to no cast at all, but it's super cheap compared to a lot of other operations that you might be doing. Or might not.

Comment: Make `doWork` a virtual method in `A` with implementations in `A` and `B`, then just `item->doWork();`

Comment: `I believe the dynamic casts at runtime will be very expensive` this is a mistake, cast is an abstraction. You'll have a trivial [virtual call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) as well as most of modern C++ compilers able to devitalize at all transactions during optimization, especially it is effective when you are using link time optimization i.e. LTO.

Comment: You could als derive A and B from the same interface (abstract baseclass) and use lists of that. No dynamic cast is needed, just a vtable call. And if you keep the interface simple it is just provides the information/call thatdoSomethingTo will need.

Comment: Considering you have a O(n²) operation, I doubt the dynamic cast will do anything to your performance. More importantly, did you _measure_?

Comment: Before taking steps to hand optimize something, you have to measure.  Because how will you know if afterwards that you really made things better, or you made them worse?  And is it worth the cost of the having the code mangled by the hand optimization?

Comment: Have you considered making `doworkB` an empty virtual function in class `A`?  I haven't benchmarked this kind of thing lately, but there was certainly a time when `dynamic_cast` was much slower than virtual functions.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner solution would probably to write some class that represents a view into the concatenated vector ranges with the base class pointer as value type. I don't think there is anything like this in the C++20 ranges library yet, so that would probably require some additional work.

Here is a solution that is specific to your case instead:

```
auto for_a_and_b = [&](auto&& f){
    for(auto item : aItems)
        f(item);
    for(auto item : bItems)
        f(item)
};

for_a_and_b([&](A* item){
    item->doWorkA();
    for_a_and_b([&](A* item2){
        if(item != item2)
            item->doSomethingTo(item2);
    });
});
```